# CSS positioning differences Safari vs. Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, safari, positioning

I have different positioning results in Safari and Chrome testing.

CSS....

```
.home #colophon  {
    margin-top: -150px;
    background-color: #000; 
    opacity: .6;
    height: 150px;  
}
.home #colophon .textwidget {
    color: #FFF;
    margin-top: -150px;
}
```

HTML...

```
<footer id="colophon" class="site-footer footer-columns" role="contentinfo">

        <div class="container footer-section">
            <div class="row">
                <h2 class="centered">
                    <?php if (bswp_option('footer-banner-title') != '') {
                        echo bswp_option('footer-banner-title');
                        } ?>
                    </h2>
                <hr>
                <div class="col-lg-4">
                    <?php dynamic_sidebar( 'footer-1' ); ?>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-4">
                    <?php dynamic_sidebar( 'footer-2' ); ?>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-4">
                    <?php dynamic_sidebar( 'footer-3' ); ?>
                </div>
        </div><!-- .row -->
    </div><!-- .containr -->
</footer><!-- #colophon -->
```

Here is my page...

http://dougragerarchitect.com/

I would like to keep my address block over the black transparent area with both browsers.